# PAM file -- Password Authentication

Tags: authentication, passwords, redhat, pam

when I am switching from one user to another user and I entered wrong password then It shows Authentication failure and shown promt. so, what should I have to do that It will ask password for 3 times(3 chances) when if it is wrong insted of show prompt ?

ex: --my system shown me like this,

[redhat@localhost~]$ su - user1 (#switch to user1)

Password: (#I enterd wrong password)

su: authentication failure

But I want like this : [redhat@localhost~]$ su - user1 (#switch to user1)

Password: (#I enterd wrong password)

su: authentication failure

Password: (#I enterd wrong password)

su: authentication failure

Password: (#I enterd correct password)

[user1@localhost ~]$